# Java PageFormat doesn't get back the right choise

Tags: java

I'm trying to catch changes from java printdialog did by the user . I've never used before it, and I haven't a good practice with this component. Now I can catch printername changing, but nothing else. I can get and set attributes by code, but not to catch the user changes.

```java
final PrintRequestAttributeSet attributes = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
attributes.add(DialogTypeSelection.NATIVE);
PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
printJob.printDialog(attributes);
PageFormat pf = printJob.defaultPage(); 
System.out.println(" orientation "+pf.getOrientation());
```

I expect to see a different orientation value after my selection in the printer proprieties.
Someone could give me some ideas on how to do it or some well-made document to understand how to manage the print user interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a solution for my question. Hope it will be usefull to someone else in my same situation.

```java
PrintRequestAttributeSet attributes = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
attributes.add(DialogTypeSelection.NATIVE);
PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

if (printJob.printDialog(attributes)) 
{
    PrintService ps=printJob.getPrintService();                 
    printerName=ps.getName();
    PageFormat pFormat = printJob.getPageFormat(attributes);
    System.out.println(" orientation "+pFormat.getOrientation());
}
```